# Can a Keras CNN predict multiple classes?

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I made a keras CNN model to predict different hand poses, and the model was not predicting the correct output. I had 10 classes. But for some images it was showing results like [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. My question is why is this happening. 
My Architecture.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), input_shape=x.shape[1:])) 
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), input_shape=x.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), input_shape=x.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=x.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=x.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=x.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer = 'adam',
          metrics = ['accuracy']
          )
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10)
```

Comment: The answer is yes, but without any code, or architecture of your CNN it's hard to understand.

Comment: I have added the architecture. @CeliusStingher Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use a `softmax` for multiclass classification?

Comment: One more thing I can see (which you probably should double check), is the `Conv2D` layers. Usually, what we call a conv layer would be translated in keras as `Conv2D` filter followed by a pooling layer. In this case, you have 2 convolutional filters one after the other. I have never seen this implementation before, so it might be the case that I have just never seen it, not that it doesn't exist so it might be worth checking other convolutional architectures in the literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `binary_crossentropy` loss which should be used for binary classification problems. For multiclass problems you should be using `categorical_crossentropy`. You might also want to change the activation on the last layer to `softmax`

This is the obvious engineering issue I can see; having said that, you probably will have to experiment with the number of layers, epochs, learning rates etc to get a working model.

Comment: Can you suggest me a something for better understanding the activation functions and thanks for answer.

Comment: I cannot think of resources from the top of my head atm, but you can see some info on the math behind them [here](https://keras.io/activations/).